# sed: sed -i "s/secret/$token/g" returning error when value of token have "/" at the end

Tags: file, sed

ERROR: `bad flag in substitute command:`

I want to update the value of  **key** inside of my config.yml

```
key: secret
```

i used this sed command to able to achieve it

```
sed -i "s/secret/$token/g" config.yml
```

But when the value of token has **"/"** at the end I'm encountering that error

something like `token="asda213123asndasd/"`

Do you how to handle this? Without removing the "/" at the end?

Comment: `cat config.yml | sed "s/secret/$(echo $token | cut -f1 -d'/')/g" > config2.yml`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you have remove the "/", i want to update it with the original value without remove the /

Comment: `cat config.yml | sed $(echo "s/secret/$(echo $token | sed 's/\//\\\//g')/g") > config2.yml`

Comment: Give us about ten lines from config.yml, containing the part you want to extract.  Also quote us the exact error that sed is giving you.

Comment: [SOLVED]

sed -i "s/secret/$(echo $token | sed 's/\//\\\//g')/g"

Thanks @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @Shua I suggest you consider a different approach for production. The regex I provided is not bulletproof. And what you're doing here looks like it's better as a `bash` script that just does `printf "key: $token\n"`